# How to redirect a path to a port on the local machine?

Tags: nginx

Given 1000 servers (which may be started on demand before they are accessed) on the local machine that are bound to ports `8000` to `9000`.

How to configure `nginx` so that the following request

```
http://my-domain.com/8505/foo/bar?id=hello
```

would be handled by

```
127.0.0.1:8505/foo/bar?id=hello
```

Is there a way to use a variable?

**Edit:** the original question talked about 5 servers, but I am looking for a mechanism to generalize the binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex; `(8[0-9][0-9][0-9]|9000)` captures numbers from 8000 to 9000 to $1.

```
location ~ ^/(8[0-9][0-9][0-9]|9000)(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$1$2?$args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use location block, something like:

```
   location /8505/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8505;
        ......
        ......
        ......
    }
```

Comment: What if I want to bind 1000 addresses. Is there a way to use a variable?